# Run browser on background

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to open a browser with vbs program on background. My program code is this:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "firefox.exe",0,True
```

The problem is that the window that opens isn't hidden. Also if I open any other program this way it runs on background eg. if I replace firefox.exe with notepad.exe.  what's wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Browsers often have many processes for UI and pages. It's likely the first `firefox.exe` only serves as a launcher, and it opens subsequent instances of `firefox.exe` that actually provides the UI. So unfortunately you can't hide the window with your current implementation.

Comment: Is there any way to achieved it?